# Laravel sync() - with multiple primary keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, composite-primary-key

How to pass an id to the `sync()` method twice?

My Laravel app contains users that may invest in companies,
and each user can invest in a company at separate times,
this is the structure of my pivot table (company_user, you may call it investments) with 3 primary keys:

- company_id *
- user_id *
- investment_date *
- investment_value

User 1 has invested twice in Company 1, on different dates
I need to use sync() method to update my pivot table:

```
    $company = Company::find(1);

    $result = $company->users()->sync([
        1 => ['investment_date' => "2021-10-29", 'investment_value' => 1000],
        1 => ['investment_date' => "2021-10-30", 'investment_value' => 2000],
        2 => ['investment_date' => "2021-11-01", 'investment_value' => 3000],
    ]);
```

But there is an error, I can't pass duplicate array keys!,
How can I achieve this?

** note that I need sync result to know which record is updated or created.